# MySQL: Access denied for user 'root@localhost' (using password:NO)

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I am trying out MySQL for the first time in a Ruby on Rails project, I am trying to use it as my default database instead of SQLite.

I have installed a copy of MySQL on my Ubuntu machine and also installed the mysql2 ruby gem, but I am having difficulties creating the database for my project.

I just created a new project after configuring the root user of MySQL with my desired password, but when I try  to run `rails db:migrate`, I get the error:

> Access denied for user 'root@localhost' (using password:NO)

I have tried a lot of tricks, but none seems to be work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here are the solutions that I tried;**

I tried changing the root password for the root user by running the code below in my terminal

```
mysql -u root -p
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
quit;
```

I tried dropping the root user and creating a new user with a new password by running the code below in my terminal

```
sudo mysql -u root
DROP USER 'root'@'localhost';
CREATE USER 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
quit;
```

I tried changing the current password policy requirements from MEDIUM to LOW by running the code below in my terminal

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'validate_password%';
SET GLOBAL validate_password_policy = 0;
```

I tried stopping and restarting MySQl service on my Ubuntu machine by running the code below in my terminal

```
sudo systemctl stop mysql
sudo systemctl start mysql
```

but unfortunately none of these worked for me.

**Here's what worked for me;**

I later opened up the `config/database.yml` file of my **Ruby on Rails** project and realized that there was no password (the password field was empty) defined for the default root username

```
default: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  username: root
  password:
  socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

All I needed to do was to type in the password that I had to configured for my root user into the password field and save it.

```
default: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  username: root
  password: mypassword
  socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

And then I ran the `rails db:migrate` code again and it worked perfectly this time, creating my **test and development databases**.

That's all.

**I hope this helps.**